# Unknown variable group_concat_max_len

Tags: mysql, configuration, group-concat

I get an error when I try to set `group_concat_max_len` in the configuration file.

```
#my.cnf
group_concat_max_len = 2048
```

I get the same error in both Windows and Linux (MySQL 5)

> mysql: unknown variable 'group_concat_max_len=2048'

Comment: (my max_allowed_packet is really enough)

Comment: command line works, --group_concat_max_len=2048

Comment: set global works, SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=2048;

Answer (score 2):

This is a dynamic variable, what happens if you try to set it whilst connected:

```
SET GLOBAL VARIABLE group_concat_max_len=2048;
```

Also, what exact version are you using?

Might it be your my.cnf file, this should be under the mysqld section, e.g.:

```
#my.cnf
[mysqld]
group_concat_max_len=2048
```

Comment: This works "SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=2048;" yes. But if i restart mysql ?

Comment: Just a thought, is that your whole my.cnf? It should be under the [mysqld] section, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, that works on Unix ! (not on Windows but we doesn't care)